# Beej Unix Sockets Error with sending / receiving

Tags: c, sockets, unix, networking, tcp

I have a client.c and server.c program that are meant to do the following: The client sends a message that says "Get\n" to the server, and the server transmits a file back to the client. Once the file transmission is done, the connections are closed.

So far, everything works up until the point where the server should receive "Get\n", and I can't seem to figure out why. I have a lot of printf() statements so that I can visually interpret everything that goes on, but that hasn't helped me fix this so I'm really hoping there's someone that can help me here!

Here is the code for my client.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <ctype.h>          
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#define PORT 43001
#define LENGTH 512 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockFD, newSockFD;
    char buff[LENGTH];
    struct sockaddr_in remote;

    //Get Socket Descriptor
    if((sockFD = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
    {
        printf("Failed to get socket descriptor\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    //Fill sockaddr struct
    remote.sin_family = AF_INET;
    remote.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &remote.sin_addr);
    bzero(&(remote.sin_zero), 8);

    //Connect to server
    if(connect(sockFD, (struct sockaddr *)&remote, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1)
    {
        printf("Failed to connect()\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Connect()ed!\n");
    }

    //Send message
    char *msg = "Get\n";
    int len, sentBytes;
    len = strlen(msg);
    printf("Sending: %s\n", msg);
    if((sentBytes = send(sockFD, msg, len, 0)) == -1)
    {
        printf("Error in sending message\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Message sent successfully!\n");
    }

    //Recieve File
    printf("Getting file from Server\n");
    char* fr_name = "/in.txt";
    FILE *fr = fopen(fr_name, "w");
    if(fr == NULL)
    {
        printf("File could not be opened\n");
    }
    else
    {
        bzero(buff, LENGTH);
        int inBlockSize = 0;
        while((inBlockSize = recv(sockFD, buff, LENGTH, 0)) > 0)
        {
            int writeSize = fwrite(buff, sizeof(char), inBlockSize, fr);
            if(writeSize < inBlockSize)
            {
                printf("File writing failed\n");
            }
            bzero(buff, LENGTH);
            if(inBlockSize == 0 || inBlockSize != 512)
            {
                break;
            }
            if(inBlockSize < 0)
            {
                printf("recv() failed due to some error\n");
            }
        }
         printf("OK received from server\n");
        fclose(fr);
    }
    close(sockFD);
    printf("Connection closed\n");
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it, this is the output I get:

```
Connect()ed!
Sending: Get (Should be Get\n but I understand why this isn't happening)

Message sent successfully!
Getting file from server
File could not be opened (This is referring to the .txt file I'm trying to write into what the server sends)
Connection closed
```

Then, for the server.c, this is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <ctype.h>          
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#define PORT 43001 
#define BACKLOG 5
#define LENGTH 512 

int main()
{
    int sockFD, newSockFD;
    int num;
    int sin_size;
    struct sockaddr_in local;
    struct sockaddr_in remote;
    char buff[LENGTH]; 
    char* fileName = "1.txt";
    char sendBuff[LENGTH];
    FILE *fs;

    //Get socket descriptor
    if ((sockFD = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
    {
        printf("Failed to get socket descriptor.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Got socket descriptor successfully\n");
    }

    //Get client socket struct
    local.sin_family = AF_INET;
    local.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    local.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    bzero(&(local.sin_zero), 8); //Deals with the rest of the struct

    //Bind
    if(bind(sockFD, (struct sockaddr*)&local, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1)
    {
        printf("Failed to bind to port\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Binded to port successfully\n");
    }

    //Listen
    if(listen(sockFD, BACKLOG) == -1)
    {
        printf("listen() failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("listen()ing to port successfully\n");
    }

    sin_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    //Accept
    if(newSockFD = accept(sockFD, (struct sockaddr *)&remote, &sin_size) == -1)
    {
        printf("accept() failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("accept()'d connection successfully\n");
    }

    //Get Message from Client
    int blkSize = 0;
    if((blkSize = recv(newSockFD, buff, LENGTH, 0)) == -1)
    {
        printf("recv()ing failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    buff[blkSize + 1] = "\0";
    printf("Client sent: %s\n", buff);

    //Open File Contents
    printf("Sending file to client\n");
    fs = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if(fs == NULL)
    {
        printf("File not found\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    bzero(sendBuff, LENGTH);
    int sendingBlkSize;

    //Send File
    while((sendingBlkSize = fread(sendBuff, sizeof(char), LENGTH, fs)) > 0)
    {
        if(send(newSockFD, sendBuff, sendingBlkSize, 0) < 0)
        {
            printf("Failed to send the file\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        bzero(sendBuff, LENGTH);
    }
    printf("Sent file to client, closing connection\n");
    close(newSockFD);
    return 0;
}
```

The output for this when ran with the client is:

```
Got socket descriptor successfully
Binded to port successfully
listen()ing to port successfully
accept()'ed connection successfully
recv()ing failed
```

So the message is sent successfully, but it is not received on the other end. I've done my best to try and troubleshoot this, but everything seems to be right to me. I'm using Beej's Guide To Network Programming to do this with Unix.

Comment: Think about the path for the file you try to open, `/in.txt`. Do you really have write-privileges in the *root* directory?

Comment: Also please refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). What is the problem you ask about? Because there's apparently two very different problems. And don't forget the *mininal*part of your [mcve].

Comment: I understand why I'm getting an error there, and I should have fixed that before posting this, so sorry for that. Also, could you clarify what you mean by the two different problems here? I believe the only issue I'm having is when it comes to my server.c program receiving a message, but if you saw a different one, I'm interested to hear what it may have been!

Comment: Use perror to show the failure reason. Regardless of what beej might say.

Comment: (The most likely issue is that the client kills the connection before the server manages to read the data.)